# Using a Loop to Create Threads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
int main()
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int policy = SCHED_FIFO;

    // sets scheduling policies of threads to FIFO
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, policy);

    // creates 3 threads
    int ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        ret = pthread_create(&(g_threadInfo[i].threadID), &attr, &thread_func, &g_threadInfo[i].arg);

        if (ret != 0)
        {
            printf("Create thread failed! Error %d", ret);
        }

        printf("Thread %d created!\n", (i + 1));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(g_threadInfo[i].threadID, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

// purpose: function for created threads
// parameters: pointer for thread variable
// returns: void pointer
void* thread_func (void* ptr)
{
    int i, sum;
    int offset = *(int *) ptr;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        sum += offset;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

What I am trying to do is create 3 separate threads using the FIFO policy. When I run the program, here is the output I get:

Thread 1 created!

Thread 2 created!

Thread 3 created!

-866347832

0

0

Ideally, I would want to have the output like so:

Thread 1 created!

499500

Thread 2 created!

499500

Thread 3 created!

499500

Here are some variables and a structure initialized before invoking main.

```
typedef struct
{
    int threadNum;
    pthread_t threadID;
    int arg;
} threadInfo;

threadInfo g_threadInfo[MAX_THREAD];
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
```

This is my first time using a loop to create threads, so I am guessing this would be the problem? An help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: The main problem I see is, that your variable `sum` is not initialized.

Comment: And where do you initialize the g_threadInfo-structures?

Comment: It is, in the thread function.

Comment: I initialized the structure at the beginning of the program, before main

Answer (score 1):

Seems like **the calling thread is faster to create another thread whereas your previous thread is still in the 1000 times loop.** So in fact, it doesn't affect the program itself, it's still efficient but your output will not correspond unless you wait for the previous thread to finish before creating another but if you do that it's like mono-thread program.

Comment: Ah okay. Then I would use the pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_wait functions, correct? Where would be good places to put these?

Comment: Maybe that could be the solution, I think you should but the pthread_cond_wait in the thread_func, first put your lock and unlock before and after the loop (less calls) and try to put you cond just after the lock.
https://gist.github.com/alexklibisz/7cffdfe90c97986f8393